# Detect stream data inside HTTP response

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, http-headers

I've created a simple proxy server, everything is working with no-streaming like video requests. As I said this is a proxy and I'm working with sockets. I want to know Is there any way to detect HTTP response contains a stream data such as a specific header which let me know this response contains streaming data? So I can detect that and use UDP to send data back to the client.

Comment: What does UDP have to do with HTTP streaming responses?

Comment: Do you mean "how to properly handle hanging gets (long poll requests) in proxy?". There is nothing particularly wrong with response not containing length and never ending...

Comment: I think you might want to make your own type of protocol where (im assuming streaming data is > a WORD LENGTH ... ) WORD LENGTH | BYTE HEADER | DATA.  You can then determine what to-do with the DATA depending on the BYTE HEADER.  i.e header 0x00 could be HTTP requesting, 0x01 could be music streaming ...